# Cross browser extension background script import error

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, google-chrome-extension, cross-browser, firefox-addon

I get: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

Whenever I try to use `import x from y` statements in the background script of my Cross browser extension [TabMerger](https://github.com/lbragile/TabMerger).

The reason I need to `import` is to separate functions & helpers from invocations as I want to test the background script.

My current file structure (differs from GitHub) is:

```
public/
  background/
    background_functions.js
    background_helpers.js
    background.js <--- error happens here when I import from ./background_functions.js & ../../src/components/App/App_functions.js

src/
  components/
    App/
      App_functions.js
```

I've tried everything I could think of, such as using `require` instead of `import` but that causes an undefined error on `require`. I want to avoid adding libraries like require.js since they are pretty heavy compared to my extension. I also tried using an HTML page to call `background.js` as a module (explained [here](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/es6-modules-in-chrome-extensions-an-introduction-313b3fce955b)) with no luck.

Comment: `<script type="module" src="background.js">` is the correct method and it works assuming you specify `.js` extension and a correct path in the import statements. Here's an [example](https://github.com/tophf/autopagerize/tree/master/bg).

Comment: The thing is that this works locally (even just importing), however, when I load unpacked in the browser, I get the error

Comment: It means you're doing something incorrectly but without [MCVE](/help/mcve) it's impossible to tell.

Comment: @wOxxOm you are 100% on the money here. The reason it didn't work for me is that I was also importing a simple translate function from `../../src/component/App/App_functions.js` in my `background.js`. So I simply repeated that 6 line function in my `background_functions.js` script and used `/* istanbul ignore next */ to exclude it from testing a second time. So using a background page which points to `background.html` that loads `background.js` as a module works. 

Are there any side effects of doing this (`background.page`) rather than using `background.scripts`?

Comment: Also I might have missed placing a `.js` at the end of my imports due to getting used to React. Ideally, you could suggest a way to import from `../../src/component/App/App_functions.js` in my `background.js` script so that I don't have to replicate the function in a `background_functions.js` script and export it, but this is very minor. In any case thank you for your time and help!

Comment: There are no downsides because even when you specify `scripts` a dummy html page is generated anyway. I can't help without [MCVE](/help/mcve), but you can inspect the example I've linked in my first comment for clues.

Comment: @wOxxOm thank you, I can confirm everything still works as expected. You can find all my files on GitHub: https://github.com/lbragile/TabMerger

Not sure if I can make a MCVE that is better than the GitHub page.

Comment: The repo should contain the updated files based on your answer and my responses.

Comment: I don't know React so I won't be able to point out errors in your repo. Looks like you're using compiler/bundler in which case you don't need to worry about imports at all - the compiler should make a single bundle out of your files anyway.